# How to convert JavaScript Date object to string that is compatible with datetime-local input?

Tags: javascript

Basically I have a Date object. How can convert it to a string compatile with `datetime-local` format *yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm*?

I tried `Date.toISOString` method, but it doesn't work as it appends `.SSSZ` at the end. Gives me the following output `The specified value "2017-04-10T17:02:00.320Z" does not conform to the required format. The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".`.

Does anyone have any **clean** solution to this problem?

Comment: @charlietfl I did my research more than enough Sir. I was clearly asking for a clean, native solution since I'm using native constructions.

Comment: I disagree about the "clearly a lack of research" comment.  I too have spent much time trying to perform the simple task of setting the default value of a `datetime-local` input to today's date.  

Of course the date format can be manually manipulated to fit the required format, but it seems like it would be such a common task that there would be a "clean" way to do it.  The `toISOString().substring(0, 16)` worked great for me.

Comment: As it turns out, I ended up using moment.js because I was getting the wrong timeszone using the `toISOString().substring(0, 16)` solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I used *moment.js* library to format the date accordingly. This line of code does the trick `moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DDTkk:mm")`.

Comment: did you mean hh instead of the kk?

Comment: Use HH (0-23), not kk (1-24) and not hh (1-12)

Answer (score 12):

Either `theDate.toISOString().substring(0, 16)`, or build the string yourself with the `getFullYear`, `getUTCDate`, `getUTCMonth` (remember it starts at 0), etc. methods. Or use a library to do it.

Comment: I was afraid that I couldn't do it without string manipulation or external lib. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Warning! This can mess up the timezone. E.g. if a user in PST selects 4pm, the value in the input field will be `2021-05-17T16:00`. If you convert that with `(new Date("2021-05-17T16:00")).toISOString()` you get `2021-05-17T23:00:00.000Z`, the time in UTC. When you cut with `substring` you just get `2021-05-17T23:00` which is *not* the value the user entered, and if you feed it back into the `datetime-local` input the user will find themselves inputting a local tz datetime and when the input field updates it will show a UTC datetime. @Lino Rabolini's answer handles this.

Answer (score 9):

use `moment.js` to format the date to the corresponding one:

`moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm')`

but **not**: `moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DDTkk:mm")`
the previous answer is **wrong** !!

kk is between 1 - 24 (which is not compatible with the textfield DateTime local)

Comment: For those still wondering, HH is 0-23 while kk is 1-24. kk breaks when showing midnight.

Answer (score 8):

I'm running into the same problem, but I didn't want to use moment or any other big lib just for a simple calculation.

I just used the ISO date but added the timezone offset, so the input doesn't go crazy when using the arrows to navigate the date values.

```
const offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 1000 * 60
const getLocalDate = value => {
    const offsetDate = new Date(value).valueOf() - offset
    const date = new Date(offsetDate).toISOString()
    return date.substring(0, 16)
}
```

basically it adds the timezone offset and converts that to an ISO date, but then we strip the timezone with the substring(0, 16)

this gives us the correct "timezoned ISO" date.

I'm giving it a try but so far it works okay. I wish this gets resolved natively, it is weird that it doesn't work out of the box.